# Android PlayFullScreenMovie

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to play a movie located in Assets/StreamingAssets in Unity 5.5b3 player is android. Movie works If I stream from internet, so format shouldn't be the problem.

This is what I'm using:

```
    filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "lt.mp4");
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie(filePath,  Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
```

However I only get a blank scene (script is attached to camera), code in Start method.

What am I missing?

Comment: How about this `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("lt.mp4",  Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);` without the `Application.streamingAssetsPath`. Try it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks, it actually works!

Can you post as answers so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the video name without the `Application.StreamingAssetsPath` url. By default, Unity will look for the video in the `StreamingAssets` directory. This is for Android. I don't know if this applies to iOS too.

```
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("lt.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.Full, FullScreenMovieScalingMode.AspectFill);
```

(Note that `Handheld` methods **do not** work in Unity Editor)

Comment: For PC or Editor, use [`MovieTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MovieTexture.Play.html) for Editor or Desktop.